# Is there anything like web.config in android?

Tags: android, eclipse

Like we have a web.config file in asp.net and others, we put several settings there to read the value and use them again and again. I was wondering if I can do the same thing in android application. For example I have a library project which has few parameters like server details etc to be set. And all these parameters are different for each application. So I write them somewhere and read the details run time.

Hope I've explained my question correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get advantage of assets folder or raw folder. Place your configuration files there.
Then in the application you can use [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) for asset folder or `context.getResources()` for raw folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used ASP.NET and have no clue what web.config is. Maybe [**SharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is what you are looking for.

Developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class with some static fields that you overwrite in your actual projects.

Library project:

```
public class ApplicationSettings {
    public static String SERVER_IP = null;
}

public class ClassThatUsesTheSettings {
    public void connect() {
        if ( ApplicationSettings.SERVER_IP == null ) {
            // No IP set by implementing project
        } else {
            // Use the settings for something smart
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing project (Possibly in `Application.onCreate()`)

```
ApplicationSettings.SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.1";
```